# Is there a list of components that exists for redhawksdr other than the ones currently in redhawk 1.10.2

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm curious to know if there are some other components out there created for redhawk, other than the ones given within the IDE, that can be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the components packaged with the REDHAWK Core Framework (http://sourceforge.net/projects/redhawksdr/files/redhawk/1.10.2/el6/x86_64/redhawk-yum-1.10.2-5-el6-x86_64.tar.gz/download), the only other components that are "officially" released at this point are the GNUHAWK components:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/redhawksdr/files/redhawk/1.10.0/el6/x86_64/gnuhawk-yum-1.10.0-2-el6-x86_64.tar.gz/download